# What is the difference between $\Delta r$ and $dr$ in Taylor series

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

All I know about Taylor series is at [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Definition). It tells how to expand a funcion to a polynomial. However I see the Taylor series at the form like this (here $r$ is a parametrized surface of $u,v$):

$$\Delta r=dr+\frac12d^2r+o(du^2+dv^2)$$

It confuses me since I don't know the difference between $\Delta r$ and  $dr$ (all I know is they are the same at 2 dimensional function, $f=f(x)$ when $\Delta x$ becomes infinitesimal). Can anybody give me a geometrical intuition of $\Delta r$ and $dr$ together with $\Delta^nr $ and $d^nr$ ?

Also, I have heard that in a higher dimension, derivatives exist not implies differentiability. Can anyone give me some examples about that?

Thirdly, I don't know when the 'infinitesimal of higher order' can be neglect. In many case we will neglect the $o(x^n)$ function. But when can we neglect and how can we know which order can we neglect?

Using the above Taylor series as example, let $n$ be an unit normal vector of the points on the surface,  my book said

$$\Delta r\cdot n=\left[dr+\frac12d^2r+o(du^2+dv^2)\right]\cdot n=\frac12d^2r\cdot n$$

Why the term $o(du^2+dv^2)$ can be neglect but not the higher or lower order of $o$ funcion?

Comment: "Also, I have heard that in a higher dimension, derivatives exist not implies differentiability. Can anyone give me some examples about that?"  This should probably be asked in a separate question.

Comment: i don't know whether it is related since I have heard that derivatives and differentiability is the meaning of Δx and dx. I wonder if I can understand the difference of them can help me understand the question.

Comment: Could you tell us which book are you using or any reference where such notation is used?

Comment: @Manuel Fdz Lpz: Sorry I can't tell you which book I am reading since it is a Chinese book. It is all about differential geometry in which $\Delta r\cdot n$ is the expression of the second fundamental form of a surface. Here $r$ is a regular surface and $n$ is the unit normal vector. The above expression tells how a point near $p$ is far away from the tangent plane of $P$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a good geometric understanding of the difference between $\Delta r$ and $dr$, look at how a [Riemann Summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum) becomes a [Riemann Integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral)

The width of each column starts as a $\Delta r$ but shrinks to a $dr$ the closer the point spacing.

[image: Riemann sum]

Comment: how about the geometrical meaning of $d^2r$ and the o function? since in your case, $\delta x=dx$ if $\delta x$ is infinitesimal. I want to have a higher dimension explanation which shows that they are difference even at infinitesimal.

Answer (score 1):

You might have read that the existence partial derivatives does not imply differentiability. One example would be $$f(x,y) = \dfrac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$$

where $f(0,0) = 0$. It should be clear that $f_x$ and $f_y$ exist and are continuous at $(0,0)$ but the original function $f(x,y)$ is not continuous at zero so it cannot be differentiable there (consider limits as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$.)

Answer (score 1):

Δr represents the **secant line** connecting two points.

dr represents the **tangent line** to the curve at the key point.

The difference between the two lines is $$\frac12d^2r+o(du^2+dv^2)$$